# Ignore a css class applied to a parent table

Tags: html, css, html-table

```
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed data_table">

    <tbody data-bind="foreach: outboundFaxLogs">
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
              <td colspan="8">
                <table>
                     <tr style="border:none">
                        <td>ReFax Status</td>
                        <td>FaxTo</td>
                        <td>Completion</td>
                        <td>FaxID</td>
                      </tr>
                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: ResubmissionHistory"">
                    <tr style="border:none">
                        <td data-bind="text: Status" ></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: FaxToNbr"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: $root.formatDateTime(CompletionTime)"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: OutboundFaxLogId"></td>
                    </tr>

                  </tbody>

                </table>
            </td>

         </tr>


    </tbody>
</table>
```

The parent table has a css class applied to it which is table-bordered. Its a twitter bootstrap style element. I don't want that style to be applied to the child table. How can I do this ? I do not want the lines that appear in between the table cells for the child table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this in your CSS

```
.table-bordered table, .table-bordered table th, .table-bordered table td {
   border:0 none;
}
```

That makes your table inside the table with class `.table-bordered` no border.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your bootstrap.css you can see that the `tr` and `td` borders are defined through

```
.table-bordered th,
  .table-bordered td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
  }
```

so if you want to change it through inline you should use

```
<tr style="border:none!important;">
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You should try to cancel style in your stylesheet :

```
.table-bordered table th,
 .table-bordered table td {
border: 0 none !important;
}
```